# Restrict index in Pandas Excelfile

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure I'm going to describe this right, but I'll try.

I have several excel files with about 20 columns and 10k or so rows. Let's say the column names are in the form col1, col2...col20.

Col2 is a timestamp column, so, for instance, a value could read: "2012-07-25 14:21:00".

I want to read the excel files into a DataFrame and perform some time series and grouping operations.

Here's some simplified code to load an excel file:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0], index_col=1) # Col2 above
```

When I run

```
df.index
```

it gives me:

```
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2012-01-19 15:37:55, ..., 2012-02-02 16:13:42]
Length: 9977, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

as expected. However, inspecting the columns, I get:

```
Index([u'Col1', u'Col2',...u'Col20'], dtype='object')
```

Which may be why I have problems with some of the manipulation I want to do. So for instance, when I run:

```
df.groupby[category_col].count()
```

I expect to get a dataframe with 1 row for each category and 1 column containing the count for that category. Instead, I get a dataframe with 1 row for each category and 19 columns describing the number of values for that column/category pair.

The same thing happens when I try to resample:

```
df.resample('D', how='count')
```

Instead of a single column Dataframe with the number of records per day, I get:

```
2012-01-01   Col1   8
             Col2   8
             Coln   8
2012-01-02   Col1   10
             Col2   10
             Coln   10
```

Is this normal behavior? How would I instead get just one value per day, category, whichever?

Comment: Is your index column the first column or literally the column at index 1? if it's the first then shouldn't you be passing 0: `df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0], index_col=0)`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's confusing. It's the second column in the excel file (I have column names in my actual code). I'll update above to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/?p=125) blog post from Wes McKinney, I think the problem is that I have to run my operations on a specific column, namely a column that I know won't have missing data.

So instead of doing:

```
df.groupby[category_col].count()
```

I should do:

```
df['col3'].groupby(df[category_col]).count()
```

and this:

```
df2.resample('D', how='count')
```

should be this:

```
df2['col3'].resample('D', how='count')
```

The results are more inline with what I'm looking for:

```
Category
Cat1    1232
Cat2    7677
Cat3    1053

Date 
2012-01-01      8
2012-01-02     66
2012-01-03     89
```